# MySQL Unknown column on clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The first query is working :

```
SELECT video.seller from video;
```

The second not:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
       t.name as tname
FROM video, type as t 
INNER JOIN user 
ON video.seller = user.id 
WHERE video.type2 = t.id 
AND thumbnail_blobKey != '' 
AND disabled = 0 
AND is_reel = 0 
AND price!= 0 
AND video.type != 4  
GROUP BY video.id 
ORDER BY video.id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

> Error :  Unknown column 'video.seller' in 'on clause'

Comment: Do you have a column "seller" in the table "video"?

Comment: yes that's why i putted the first query :)

Comment: why are you mixing JOIN syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting example.  Better formatted:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, t.name as tname
FROM video, type as t INNER JOIN
     user
     ON video.seller = user.id
WHERE video.type2 = t.id AND
     thumbnail_blobKey != '' AND disabled = 0 AND is_reel = 0 AND price!= 0 AND video.type != 4 
GROUP BY video.id
ORDER BY video.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

The issue is the the columns of `video` are not understood in the rest of the `from` clause because of the `,`.  This is how the comma works.  Interestingly, it can be fixed just by replacing the `,` with its logical equivalent `cross join`:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, t.name as tname
FROM video cross join type as t INNER JOIN
     user
     ON video.seller = user.id
WHERE video.type2 = t.id AND
     thumbnail_blobKey != '' AND disabled = 0 AND is_reel = 0 AND price!= 0 AND video.type != 4 
GROUP BY video.id
ORDER BY video.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This is explained in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) and the reason is precedence.  The comma has lower precedence than `cross join`.  So the joins in your expression are evaluated as "video join (type join user)".  Because the second join is interpreted first, the columns in `video` are not known.

However, there is really a join on the table, so it is better written as:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, t.name as tname
FROM video join
     type t
     on video.type2 = t.id INNER JOIN
     user
     ON video.seller = user.id
WHERE thumbnail_blobKey != '' AND disabled = 0 AND is_reel = 0 AND price!= 0 AND video.type != 4 
GROUP BY video.id
ORDER BY video.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is written now you are trying to join tables `type`, and `user` with condition that `video.seller = user.id` . As video.seller is nether a column of table `type` or `user`, you have an error.

Changing to the following would remove this error:

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
       t.name AS tname
FROM video
INNER JOIN USER ON video.seller = USER.id,
                                       TYPE AS t
WHERE video.type2 = t.id
  AND thumbnail_blobKey != ''
  AND disabled = 0
  AND is_reel = 0
  AND price!= 0
  AND video.TYPE != 4
GROUP BY video.id
ORDER BY video.id DESC LIMIT 0,
                             10
```

Comment: Thank you meewoK, Gordon got it fixed as well

Comment: NP, Gordon's final solution is much cleaner!